# Selenium with PhantomJs and NodeJs

Tags: node.js, selenium

i created a project with Express, and now i try to run selenium code with Phantomjs.

I have:

```
var app = express();

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs()).
   build();
```

but when i try to run i have this error:

```
path/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/phantomjs.js:72
    throw Error(
          ^
Error: The PhantomJS executable could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version from http://phantomjs.org/download.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH. For more information, see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at findExecutable (/home/antonio/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/phantomjs.js:72:11)
    at Object.createDriver (/home/antonio/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/phantomjs.js:108:13)
    at createNativeDriver (/home/antonio/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:43:24)
    at Builder.build (/home/antonio/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:96:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/antonio/projectNode/ExpressProject/app.js:18:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Comment: have you installed phantomjs package?

Comment: yes i install phantomjs;phantom;selenium-webdriver and webdriverjs

Comment: Then you have to run your selenium driver webdriver-manager start

you could refer following link for manual fix PATH http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/headless-functional-testing-with-selenium-and-phantomjs--net-30545

Comment: i have run selenium driver webdriver and now i have this error: /node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1643
      throw error;
            ^
Error: Wait timed out after 1109ms

Comment: i try to start with:  java -jar path/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="/home/ant/chromedriver" but still i have this error

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Phantom JS package for you OS, I am on Ubuntu so I did this

```
sudo apt-get install phantomjs
```

and this error gone, if you already installed phantomjs package, then something gone wrong with your path settings, set you path variable for phantomjs